# Expand a shape in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

Is there a way in Sketch to expand a shape? For example, let's say I have an outline of something. I'd like to expand that outline to be a solid shape so I can apply boolean operations to it with other shapes. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "expand"? Why don't you just fill it? Or resize (while holding SHIFT) if you want to change size.

Comment: I'd like to be able to apply boolean operations on the stroke. A example would be to make [this image](http://i.imgur.com/4325J6R.png). You have to expand the stroke to create a solid outline, as opposed to a path with a width. Then you subtract a diagonal shape from it, leaving the blank space.

Comment: Please include external images in your post so we can all see them - some of us work behind a firewall where sites like imgur are blocked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The accepted answer seems to be deprecated as of Sketch 3.6.1

**Layer > Paths > Vectorize Stroke** is gone, instead now we got
**Layer > Convert to Outlines**

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT for Sketch 3.6.1**

Choose Layer > Convert to Outlines.

---

Strokes cannot be expanded (currently, v2.4.3). **Edit:** You can choose vectorize stroke in **Layer** (or Edit for older version) > **Paths** > **Vectorize Stroke**

However, you could create the shape and then use a mask to make the diagonal cut.
In the example I have made the mask visible in red (normally this would not be shown).

[image: shape (black/white) with mask(red)]

You can create a mask by drawing a single shape (can be constructed using boolean shapes).
Then select 'Use as Mask' when ctrl-clicking the layer in the layer pane.
Make sure you position the layer right **below** the layer you want to mask (in the layer pane).

Comment: Turns out you _can_ expand strokes in v2.4.3.

Go to the **Edit** menu, select **Paths** and then select **Vectorize Stroke**.

Comment: Don't have the rep to reply to the selected answer, but at least as of `Version 3.1.1`, it's now under **Layer > Paths > Vectorize Stroke**.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with arrow ends, at least in Sketch 43.2

Comment: @Eric: there  might be plugins that will make it work with arrowheads... I found this one, but it has not been updated in a while...
https://github.com/joclin/arrowfy

Answer (score 0):

Choose the border you want to convert into the shape and go to **Layer > Convert to outline**

That's it.